# Anyone familiar with "Unhandled exception Error: EndUpdateResource: Windows Error #5"?

Tags: air

Someone trying to install my desktop app (AIR) keeps getting the "Installer has been misconfigured" error, but the steps I normally following when troubleshooting this aren't fixing the problem.

One of the last entries on their log file for the install is...

```
Native installation package creation failed: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Unhandled exception Error: EndUpdateResource: Windows Error #5" errorID=0]
```

Is anyone here familiar with

```
Unhandled exception Error: EndUpdateResource: Windows Error #5
```

as Adobe haven't an answer, and not much is turning up in research.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I'm getting this now on Windows 7. Did you ever find out the cause and a solution? The OSX install of the same .air file works fine.

Comment: No solution as yet. Although I did find that closing any open Adobe programs before installing an AIR file can fix the "Installer has been misconfigured" problem in some cases.

Comment: I think I found the problem with that one: in an attempt to solve other issues, I was using an `extendedDesktop`profile with a .air format; switching to `desktop` made this particular install issue go away. Still get others though – if one of the check boxes ("open immediately") in the installer is checked or the other isn't.

Comment: Oh wait,I spoke too soon: it's back. Arrgh!

Comment: I had one user find that making sure there are no Adobe updater programs open helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following conditions in you environment

- Firewall is on
- Realtime scanning is on

Set them all `OFF` and try to do the process from the beginning.